# Generating animation on dynamic listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a clicked 60 seconds animated pie button timer to each list item. Each list view is generated by javascript.

I have tried different things but I can never make it work to generate each row with the pie timer inside, with each one to have different time depending on the click.

For better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish here is the timer animation with the list row creation: [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/claire89/qye2bamp/3/)

Some code for the list view creation:

```
 var listCreated = false;

 function appendToList() {

     //Create the listview if not created
     if (!listCreated) {
         $("#content").append("<ul id='list' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'></ul>");
         listCreated = true;
         $("#content").trigger("create");
     }
     $("#list").append("<li>Item</li>");
     $("#list").listview("refresh");

 }
```

I'm new to jQuery mobile so the help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: You can add multiple pies like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qye2bamp/4/ ; however, your plugin only allows one pie to run at a time. If you start a second one while another is running, the first stops at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using wont work, because you use the same ID for each timer. On a document they need to be unique name when using ID's. A workaround is to have 2 classes (timer and timera) and uppon click you replace the list item with the timer animation and start it.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/furhpjah/

**New code**

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function () {
$(".timer").replaceWith("<div class='timera'>0</div>");
$(this).replaceWith("<li><a><div class='timer'></div>Timer Running</a></li>");
$("#list").listview("refresh");
runTimer() 
});
```

Comment: Nice work Tasos! However, if a timer is already running and you add a second one. Clicking the second one resets the first instead of letting it run concurrently...

Comment: I haven't gone that far M8. :)) But you can remove the ($(".timer").replaceWith("<div class='timera'>0</div>");) at least you see were the timer has stopped.  demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/3nv6hm7k/